# Create quick reference variables for speed access to core prototypes

Tags: javascript

I was analyzing some third party javascript libraries and came across an approach wherein people create quick reference to core prototypes. Is there any performance benefit of doing this ? Can anyone explain this with an example ?

```
var ArrayProto = Array.prototype, ObjProto = Object.prototype, FuncProto = Function.prototype;

// Create quick reference variables for speed access to core prototypes.
var
    push             = ArrayProto.push,
    slice            = ArrayProto.slice,
    concat           = ArrayProto.concat,
    toString         = ObjProto.toString,
    hasOwnProperty   = ObjProto.hasOwnProperty;
```

Comment: *"Can anyone explain this with an example ?"* I'm afraid I don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: Just to understand what you said correctly, would test_1() be faster than test_2() ? Although your answer was very elaborate, i am still confused how test_2() can be faster

function test_1() {

var result = [1,2,3];
result.push(4);
}

function test_2() {
var ArrayProto = Array.Prototype;
var push = ArrayProto.push;

var result = [1,2,3];
result.push(4);
}

Comment: Yes, `test_1` would be faster than `test_2`. `test_2` does two lookups it never does anything useful with after. That code doesn't demonstrate what the code in the question is doing at all.

Comment: Its basically the code from underscore.js. In case, we do a lookup can you please tell me how those lookups can be useful ? An example ?

Comment: I've added an example to the answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any performance benefit of doing this ?

A **very** small one, yes, for two/three reasons:

1. When you reference an identifier (for instance, `Array` or `ArrayProto` or `push`), the JavaScript engine first looks in the current lexical environment and then, if it's not found, the next one out, and the next one out, etc., until it reaches the global lexical environment. I assume the code you're referring to is within a scoping function. So because those are locals within the scoping function, they're found right away, rather than the JavaScript engine having to traverse up to the global environment to find them.
2. `Array.prototype` not only requires looking up `Array`, but also the `prototype` property on `Array`. It doesn't take any appreciable time, but it doesn't take *zero* time, either.
3. (Sort of #2 repeated) Looking up `Array.prototype.push` also requires looking up `push` on `Array.prototype`. Again, not appreciable, but again, not zero, either.

So the combination of those can make a **very** small performance difference, using a local `push` rather than `Array.prototype.push` (and so on).

**More likely, though**, the author did it because it made for less typing, rather than as a performance enhancement. :-)

---

Re an example: It's frequently useful to use a function like `Array.prototype.slice` on an object that isn't an array. In fact, until ES2015's `Array.from`, it was one of the canonical ways to turn an *array-like* object (such as the collection returned from `querySelectorAll`) into a true array (more in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476)).

So given the setup in your question, if I have an *array-like* list:

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll("some-selector-here");
```

instead of doing this to get that list as an array:

```
var trueArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(list);
```

I can do this instead:

```
var trueArray = slice.call(list);
```

Since `slice` is likely to be in the current lexical environment or the one just outside it, it's found fairly quickly (point #1 above), and then we're done, rather than having to look up `prototype` on `Array` (point #2 above) and then look up `slice` on `Array.prototype` (point #3 above).

So it's **very** slightly faster; but again, primarily, it's shorter and less error-prone to type.

Comment: _More likely, though, the author did it because it made for less typing_ also for a smaller library, depending on how many times it's used it could save a lot of bytes.

Comment: @George: True, although that aspect (reducing size on the wire) we normally leave to minifiers.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to do a lot of Array.prototype in your function, you might want to grab a copy of the function reference into a variable for reuse. This would provide a small performance benefit.